# show that $x_{1}+x_{2}<1$

Tags: functions, inequality

Given $m\in\mathbb{R}$, assume that the equation $x\ln{x}=m$ has two real roots $x_1,x_2$. Show that:
$$x_{1}+x_{2}<1.$$

---

My attempt. Since
$$x_{1}\ln{x_{1}}=x_{2}\ln{x_{2}}=m$$
 if we let $$f(x)=x\ln{x}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\ln{x}+1=0$$

Comment: Have you tried plotting $x\ln(x)$? It should give you a good idea of how to go about your proof. In fact, your idea of using derivatives is already a pretty good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x\log x$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and
$$ f(1)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0,$$
so we may have two real solutions only if $m$ belongs to $f((0,1])$. Such range is $\left[-\frac{1}{e},0\right]$ since the only stationary point of $f(x)$ occurs at $x=\frac{1}{e}$. So we have $m\in\left(-\frac{1}{e},0\right)$. Assume that $x_1\in\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)$. In order to prove the claim, it is enough to show that
$$ g(x) = f(x)-f(1-x) $$
is negative over the interval $\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)$. That is pretty easy, since $g(x)$ is a convex function$^{(*)}$ on $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $g\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)<0$. Proof of $(*)$:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(f(x)-f(1-x)\right) = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Comment: Nice,Maybe  $x_{1}+x_{2}<m+1$ also hold?

Comment: @functionsug: that is non-trivial but since $m=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}$ you may simply try to adjust the above lines by replacing the $g$ function with the suitable candidate.